# Export Dataframe to Table in Latex

Tags: tables, python

[image]

I am new to Latex

I need to add the data of above into table (in latex). I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` which evaluates this result. and I know the use of `.to_latex()`. But after that I don't know how to add this data into table?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `to_latex()` makes a finished `tabular`, so you just need to write that to a file, and use `\input` in your LaTeX document.

Assuming Python 3, here is a minimal Python example to make a DataFrame and save as a text file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['Foo','Bar','Baz'])
with open('mytable.tex','w') as tf:
    tf.write(df.to_latex())
```

A minimal LaTeX example using the exported table code, will then be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\input{mytable}
\end{document}
```

The `booktabs` package is required as `to_latex()` uses its commands for table rules. This assumes that `mytable.tex` is in the same folder.

Comment: I tried the above thing . I tried to print content that work fine. but I am unable to get my table in my latex pdf :(

Comment: @user144631 What exactly did you do, and exactly how did it fail? (Did you print to a file? Did you `\input` that file in your document?)

Comment: I got now . Thankyou for your help :D

Comment: No worries. Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer. (The same goes for the answers to your other question.)

Comment: Sure , Bdw is there any method to drop index of dataframe before writing to latex table ?

Comment: I dont have  15 reputation to upvote or select answer . sorry :(

Comment: @pritisharma Ah right, forgot about that limitation for upvoting. Reading the `to_latex()` documentation (e.g .via df.to_latex? in an IPython shell), there is an `index` keyword that you can pass `False` to. `df.to_latex(index=False)`

Comment: Yay it worked. Thankyou so much :D You are genious . I was trying to set same thing but before applying df.to_latex()

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TorbjørnT. One thing that I would add for the lazy people like me is to `\begin{table} \input{mutable.tex} \end{table}`

Comment: @paolopazzo Well, you don't need to use a `table` environment, so I don't really think my answer needs it either. (And if you do I'd guess you'd probably want to have a caption as well ...?)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I didn't mean in any way to say that your answer is incomplete, I just thought that could be helpful to add the table environment to have a more complete structure (yes also with a caption and a label if one needs it :-) ). If you think that my comment doesn't add anything valuable to your answer I will delete it, no problem.

Comment: @paolopazzo Sorry if my last comment sounded a bit harsh :) I won't add the `table` environment to my answer, but feel free to leave your comment.